# What is the recommended way to access a non-global bloc/cubit in a named route

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-provider

currently, I have as an example a cubit that is injected with `BlocProvider` in `ScreenA`.

```
class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<MyCubit>(
      create: (context) => MyCubit(),
      child: ...
    );
  }
}
```

For the widget sub-tree the `MyCubit` cubit will be available to use, right?

Now, If I have another route `ScreenB` that I want to pass that cubit to, it will be available as well in that route:

```
class ScreenA extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<MyCubit>(
      create: (context) => MyCubit(),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/screenB");
        },
        child: Text('Screen A'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

as you can see, I can't pass that cubit to that `ScreenB` via constructor since we have a named route, and so in order to pass it I use currently the `arguments` property in the `Navigator`'s `pushNamed` method like this:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/screenB", arguments: context.read<MyCubit>());
```

and in the `ScreenB`, I read it like this:

```
class ScreenB extends StatelessWidget {
  const ScreenB({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cubit = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as MyCubit;
    return BlocProvider<MyCubit>.value(
      value: cubit,
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}
```

but as you can see, now I did list the Dart's types system and I need now to cast the `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments` to my cubit, in addition, if I will need to change something in `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments`, I will have now to reflect changes in other places, and this always ends up wasting my time and be error-prone.

My question is:

**What is the better option that I can do to pass a cubit to another named route without needing to cast its type or to relate it to other arguments so it will not be error-prone for me ?**

Note: I don't talk about global blocs/cubits, I need to create a cubit/bloc in a specific nested route and want it to be available in others as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is easily done in any other way than with a package such as `AutoRoute` if you want to create the blocs on ScreenA and cannot/don't want to create them when defining your named routes in the `MaterialApp` or e.g. `onGenerateRoute`.

That is obviously done with blocs defined when creating the MaterialApp. They are **not** global in the common sense as they can absolutely be made private to the MaterialWidget, and only passed to the correct routes.

So something like this:

```
class AppRouter {
  final MyCubit _cubit = MyCubit();

  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings routeSettings) {
    switch (routeSettings.name) {
      case '/screenA':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _cubit,
            child: ScreenA(),
          ),
        );
      case '/screenB':
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
            value: _cubit,
            child: ScreenB(),
          ),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Then attach the router to the MaterialApp, something like this:

```
final _appRouter = AppRouter();
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Title',
  onGenerateRoute: _appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
)
```

But (maybe you already know) you can provide the bloc using BlocProvider.value() wrapping the MaterialRoute with non-named routing when you are on ScreenA:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
      value: context.read<MyCubit>(),
      child: ScreenB(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Or using e.g. AutoRoute in a bunch of different ways. Such as Nested Routing as already explained in a different answer, or you can pass the bloc as a type safe parameter to the generated route for ScreenB. Something like this:

```
AutoRouter.of(context).push(ScreenBRoute(bloc: context.read<MyCubit>()))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but declaring the cubit with ` final MyCubit _cubit = MyCubit();` will cause to execution of the constructor of the cubit as soon as the `AppRouter` class is read. to be precise, it will be executed immediately when the app is opened. this is the problem, since I have an app thet contains an authentication screen and a home screen, if I initialize the bloc without a previously authenticated user, the app will just crash

Comment: I want to initialize the bloc inside my nested route, and pass it to other screens without losing it's type when navigating with named routes

Comment: Yes, thank you! I'am awae that I can pass it in the screen constructor if I use direct navigating with `push()`, but I'am talking in the case of named routes

Comment: Yeah well the part about crashing when not authenticated can obviously (should at least be possible) be solved by smarter states etc. But if you're not against using a routing package, I strongly recommend AutoRoute or similar as that solves a lot of problems. This as well as other... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested routes. Essentially, ScreenA and ScreenB can have the same ancestor, and your Bloc can be injected on the Wrapper route.

Basically something like this

```
BlocProvider<MyCubit>
  NestedWrapperPage
    Navigator
      - ScreenA
      - ScreenB
```

[The flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav#generate-nested-routes) might help you with setting this up.

As an alternative to the official docs (and I highly recommend), consider using [AutoRoute](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) to manage your navigation logic. Setting up [nested routes](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#nested-navigation) would be a breeze with this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I did mentioned that I am not talking about global blocs, since it just can't be on same cases, I need to inject my bloc inside a nested route and read it in the other